# Use axios call as src of image

Tags: reactjs

I am sending an id as a prop to a child component which needs to do an API call with the id. The api returns some binary data from image files. I am using axios to deal with the request. I am also getting the result in the `.then()` but I am confused as to how to use this data and hook it up with the image tag in the `render()` function.

```
getImages = (id) => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/getImage?id=" + id)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
  }

render() {
    return (<img src={this.getImages(this.props.id)}/>);
}
```

**Update 1:**

I have tried setting the state from the `.then()` but I guess it causes to re-render and the application crashes from the front end.

Comment: Can you use `<img src={"http://localhost:5000/getImage?id=" + this.props.id} />`?

Comment: @NikitaMadeev this does the trick just as I wanted. Thanks a lot. Can you also say if this will work with audio files too? But there won't be any audio component in the page but rather be used from JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the result of your axios call in state, so that when you update state, your component will re-render and your `<img>` element will have the updated value for the `src` attribute.

```js
function App(props) {
  const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/getImage?id=" + props.id).then(res => {
      setImgSrc(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return imgSrc !== null ? <img src={imgSrc} /> : null;
}
```

In the above solution, we initialize the state to a `null` value and then call axios when the component mounts (via the `useEffect`). Then, once we have the response from the API, we update the `imgSrc` state and then the component will re-render and populate the correct `src` attribute in the `<img>` element.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did the trick! Thank you so much.